# nx.js using capacitor Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/app-root'

Tags: capacitor, nxjs

In my NX project, I have a capacitor Angular 14 application, when using cap:sync, I get the following error which stomps me.

```
> nx run caregiver:sync:ios --verbose=true


 >  NX   Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/app-root'

   Require stack:
   - /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nxtend/capacitor/node_modules/@nrwl/devkit/index.js
   - /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nxtend/capacitor/src/executors/cap/executor.js
   - /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js
   - /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/nx/src/command-line/run.js
   - /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/nx/bin/run-executor.js

Error: Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/app-root'
Require stack:
- /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nxtend/capacitor/node_modules/@nrwl/devkit/index.js
- /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nxtend/capacitor/src/executors/cap/executor.js
- /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js
- /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/nx/src/command-line/run.js
- /Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/nx/bin/run-executor.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yannickdesjardins/Documents/GitHub/nx-c4g/nx-c4g/node_modules/@nxtend/capacitor/node_modules/@nrwl/devkit/index.js:182:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

My nx report is the following: I use node 16, nx 14 and capacitor 13. I have research on the subject but can't seem to find the right answer.

Comment: I tried using pnpm as mentionned in github.com/nxtend-team/nxtend/issues/632, however upgrading to PNPM to apply the patch creates havoc in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was difficult to find an answer online. Here is how I fixed this issue

First ran the `nx report`, then checked the `nx` version and `@nrwl/<package>` versions are the same.

For me the `nx` version was `14.4.2` and the `@nrwl/react` was `14.8.2` this was causing the issue I believe. Changing the version of `@nrwl/react` to `14.4.2` fixed it for me.
I just went ahead changed the `@nrwl/node` and `@nrwl/js` versions to `14.4.2` from `14.4.3` (say that I'm cautious)

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible the module has simply moved and NX failed to migrate some of your code.

In my case, I had to replace instances of:

```js
const { registerTsProject } = require('nx/src/utils/register');
```

with

```js
const { registerTsProject } = require('nx/src/plugins/js/utils/register');
```